# SVG not rendered properly when using USE tag

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG not rendered properly when using `use` tag. Tried using the same SVG tag without using `use` tag, This time i had luck and it works properly.

Unfortunately i need `use` tag to render my SVG properly. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Refer my code below

```html
   <!-- SVG which I'm trying to reuse using `use` tag--->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="17" width="17" style="display:none">
      <symbol id="check">
        <defs>
          <rect id="addColumn_a" width="16" height="16" y=".996" rx="1"/>
          <mask id="addColumn_b" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" fill="white">
            <use xlink:href="#addColumn_a"/>
          </mask>
        </defs>
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(0 -.996)">
          <rect width="16" height="1" y="6" fill="#404040"/>
          <rect width="16" height="1" y="11" fill="#404040"/>
          <rect width="15" height="1" x="3.028" y="8.565" fill="#404040" transform="rotate(-90 10.528 9.065)"/>
          <rect width="15.348" height="1" x="-2.141" y="8.554" fill="#5C5C5C" transform="rotate(-90 5.533 9.054)"/>
          <use stroke="#404040" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#addColumn_b)" xlink:href="#addColumn_a"/>
          <rect width="16" height="6" x="-5" y="5.996" fill="#19AF5C" opacity=".651" transform="rotate(-90 3 8.996)" rx="1"/>
        </g>
      </symbol>
</svg> 

 <!-- USE Link reference which is not rendering SVG properly--->

<svg height="17" width="17">
      <use xlink:href="#check"></use>
</svg>


 <!-- Same SVG tag just a small change removed `symbol` tag--->


<svg height="17" width="17">
      <defs>
        <rect id="a" width="16" height="16" y=".996" rx="1"/>
        <mask id="b" width="16" height="16" x="0" y="0" fill="white">
          <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(0 -.996)">
        <rect width="16" height="1" y="6" fill="#404040"/>
        <rect width="16" height="1" y="11" fill="#404040"/>
        <rect width="15" height="1" x="3.028" y="8.565" fill="#404040" transform="rotate(-90 10.528 9.065)"/>
        <rect width="15.348" height="1" x="-2.141" y="8.554" fill="#5C5C5C" transform="rotate(-90 5.533 9.054)"/>
        <use stroke="#404040" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#b)" xlink:href="#a"/>
        <rect width="16" height="6" x="-5" y="5.996" fill="#19AF5C" opacity=".651" transform="rotate(-90 3 8.996)" rx="1"/>
      </g>
</svg>
```

P.S I have rendered this SVG code using tools, Not an hand written code

Comment: By "not rendering properly", what do you mean? Are you referring to the thicker line around the outside?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an SVG created with Illustrator.

For some reason AI likes to create SVGs that have weird extra masks and/or clipPaths.  It always seem to be causing problems for people.  It may b a good idea to use a different program for creating icons. Eg. Inkscape or Sketch.

Your problem is due to some weird interaction between the mask and the symbol. I gave up trying to figure it out, because it was quicker just to rewrite the icon to get rid of the mask and simplify it.

If you have multiple icons to fix, then this solution doesn't really help you I guess. But here you go anyway:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="17" width="17" style="display:none">
  <symbol id="check2">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <rect width="16" height="1" y="5" fill="#404040"/>
      <rect width="16" height="1" y="10" fill="#404040"/>
      <rect width="1" height="16" x="10" fill="#404040"/>
      <rect width="1" height="16" x="5" fill="#5C5C5C"/>
      <rect width="15" height="15" x="0.5" y="0.5" rx="0.5" stroke="#404040" stroke-width="1"/>
      <rect width="6" height="16" fill="#19AF5C" opacity=".651" rx="1"/>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg> 


<svg height="17" width="17">
      <use xlink:href="#check2"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: i have multiple icons to get fixed. Anyway thanks for this solution. This will be not be a good idea for me to work it

Comment: `That looks like an SVG created with Illustrator […] use a different program […] Eg. Illustrator…` The first seems to be referring to some [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) - which is the different one?

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo. I meant Inkscape I think.